Rosapi: service `rosapi/message_details` fails using roslibjs/rosbridge-server or the command line
Description
I had an issue trying to get a common message definition through roslibjs and rosbridge server. I had an issues so I tried to mimic the request with the command line and it crashed similarly.

Library Version: 2.1.0
ROS Version: Jazzy
Platform / OS: Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS

Steps To Reproduce
ros2 service call /rosapi/message_details rosapi_msgs/srv/MessageDetails "{'type': 'sensor_msgs/JointState'}"

or
ros2 service call /rosapi/message_details rosapi_msgs/srv/MessageDetails "{type: 'sensor_msgs/JointState'}"

Expected Behavior
I would expect to get something like:
std_msgs/Header header
string[] name
float64[] position
float64[] velocity
float64[] effort

Actual Behavior
rosapi node crashes. Here are the complete logs I get, with a KeyError: 'check_fields'
[rosapi_node-5] /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/cache.py:215: Warning: W:Target Packages (main/binary-arm64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2-latest.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2.list:1, W:Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2-latest.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2.list:1, W:Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-arm64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2-latest.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2.list:1, W:Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2-latest.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2.list:1
[rosapi_node-5]   self._depcache = apt_pkg.DepCache(self._cache)
[rosapi_node-5] Traceback (most recent call last):
[rosapi_node-5]   File "/opt/ros/jazzy/lib/rosapi/rosapi_node", line 329, in <module>
[rosapi_node-5]     main()
[rosapi_node-5]   File "/opt/ros/jazzy/lib/rosapi/rosapi_node", line 321, in main
[rosapi_node-5]     rclpy.spin(node)
[rosapi_node-5]   File "/opt/ros/jazzy/lib/python3.12/site-packages/rclpy/__init__.py", line 244, in spin
[rosapi_node-5]     executor.spin_once()
[rosapi_node-5]   File "/opt/ros/jazzy/lib/python3.12/site-packages/rclpy/executors.py", line 827, in spin_once
[rosapi_node-5]     self._spin_once_impl(timeout_sec)
[rosapi_node-5]   File "/opt/ros/jazzy/lib/python3.12/site-packages/rclpy/executors.py", line 822, in _spin_once_impl
[rosapi_node-5]     raise handler.exception()
[rosapi_node-5]   File "/opt/ros/jazzy/lib/python3.12/site-packages/rclpy/task.py", line 239, in __call__
[rosapi_node-5]     self._handler.send(None)
[rosapi_node-5]   File "/opt/ros/jazzy/lib/python3.12/site-packages/rclpy/executors.py", line 508, in handler
[rosapi_node-5]     await call_coroutine()
[rosapi_node-5]   File "/opt/ros/jazzy/lib/python3.12/site-packages/rclpy/executors.py", line 447, in _execute
[rosapi_node-5]     response = await await_or_execute(srv.callback, request, srv.srv_type.Response())
[rosapi_node-5]                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[rosapi_node-5]   File "/opt/ros/jazzy/lib/python3.12/site-packages/rclpy/executors.py", line 111, in await_or_execute
[rosapi_node-5]     return callback(*args)
[rosapi_node-5]            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[rosapi_node-5]   File "/opt/ros/jazzy/lib/rosapi/rosapi_node", line 228, in get_message_details
[rosapi_node-5]     dict_to_typedef(d) for d in objectutils.get_typedef_recursive(request.type)
[rosapi_node-5]                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[rosapi_node-5]   File "/opt/ros/jazzy/lib/python3.12/site-packages/rosapi/objectutils.py", line 115, in get_typedef_recursive
[rosapi_node-5]     return _get_typedefs_recursive(type, [])
[rosapi_node-5]            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[rosapi_node-5]   File "/opt/ros/jazzy/lib/python3.12/site-packages/rosapi/objectutils.py", line 285, in _get_typedefs_recursive
[rosapi_node-5]     typedef = get_typedef(type)
[rosapi_node-5]               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[rosapi_node-5]   File "/opt/ros/jazzy/lib/python3.12/site-packages/rosapi/objectutils.py", line 91, in get_typedef
[rosapi_node-5]     type_def = _get_typedef(instance)
[rosapi_node-5]                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[rosapi_node-5]   File "/opt/ros/jazzy/lib/python3.12/site-packages/rosapi/objectutils.py", line 149, in _get_typedef
[rosapi_node-5]     fieldnames, fieldtypes, fieldarraylen, examples = _handle_array_information(instance)
[rosapi_node-5]                                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[rosapi_node-5]   File "/opt/ros/jazzy/lib/python3.12/site-packages/rosapi/objectutils.py", line 178, in _handle_array_information
[rosapi_node-5]     field_type, arraylen = _handle_type_and_array_len(instance, name)
[rosapi_node-5]                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[rosapi_node-5]   File "/opt/ros/jazzy/lib/python3.12/site-packages/rosapi/objectutils.py", line 194, in _handle_type_and_array_len
[rosapi_node-5]     field_type = instance._fields_and_field_types[name[1:]]
[rosapi_node-5]                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^
[rosapi_node-5] KeyError: 'check_fields'
[ERROR] [rosapi_node-5]: process has died [pid 6530, exit code 1, cmd '/opt/ros/jazzy/lib/rosapi/rosapi_node --ros-args -r __node:=rosapi --params-file /tmp/launch_params_rv4kl86a --params-file /tmp/launch_params_h27onfib --params-file /tmp/launch_params_7_wghq8v'].

